# How to use .ini file in visual C# project

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, ini

I am working on Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express. I am using database on Microsoft Access 2007. Now in the end, I have to store the names of all products from database to INI file. Please help me. I am new to this.

Comment: Do you mean you are reading records from an Access Database and storing them to an INI file? An INI file is just a plain text file so you could use a `TextWriter` for the job.

Comment: Actually i have to use INI file in my project. I have two textboxes containing product names. I transfer one product to another textbox using button click. Then in the end, those which are moved on second textbox, I have to show 2 in that product Section, otherwise 1.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't understand what you mean? I have no knowledge of your application so saying things like "Product Section" doesn't mean much. Are you reading / writing to INI file? What has Access got to do with it then?

Comment: There are SECTIONS in ini file. So there will be a Section for each Product Name in my database. I want to show "2" in the Section of those Product Names which are moved to another textbox. And "1" in the Section of those Product Names which remain in first textbox only.

Comment: Using INI files is pretty old school so there isn't much support now. You will either need to use something like @StuporMundi has suggested or use `TextReader` and `TextWriter` to build up the INI file manually.

Comment: Here's a basic class to help with INI files:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1966/An-INI-file-handling-class-using-C  We had to support legacy programs that used INI files; we used the more extensive library from here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5304/Read-Write-XML-files-Config-files-INI-files-or-the

Comment: @MatthewWatson thankz for ua reply but i have already seen that article. That was a complete program for using INI file using class. But i just want to write some product names from my project into INI file. I am getting nothing from that article. Would you plzz explain me a little..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Microsoft considers ini-files deprecated (see comments in the documentation of e.g. `GetPrivateProfileString`) and has not included direct support for them in the Common Language Runtime. One easy way to use them anyway is to import the Windows SDK functions `Get/SetPrivateProfileString` and `Get/SetPrivateProfileInt` (exported by the Kernel32.dll) using the `DllImportAttribute` from `System.Runtime.InteropServices`.

Comment: I am trying such a thing..

Comment: You can find decent `DllImport` statements on [GetPrivateProfileString](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.getprivateprofilestring) and the associated pages.

Comment: Thankzz a lott everyone..
I have solved it now :)